# NoClassDefFoundError with Android Unit Test project at run time

Tags: android, unit-testing

Everything compiles fine, but when I run my android tests and I get an error where the project class is instantiated. Example:

```
package com.lognllc.plyfe.model;

import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;
import com.lognllc.plyfe.model.PlyfeModel;


public class PlyfeModelTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {
    private PlyfeModel model;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() {
        model = new PlyfeModel();
    }

    public void testSet() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

When I build and run the test I get:

```
test:

 [echo] Running tests ...
 [exec] 
 [exec] com.lognllc.plyfe.model.PlyfeModelTest:
 [exec] Error in testSet:
 [exec] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.lognllc.plyfe.model.PlyfeModel
 [exec]     at com.lognllc.plyfe.model.PlyfeModelTest.setUp(PlyfeModelTest.java:12)
 [exec]     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
 [exec]     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
 [exec]     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
 [exec]     at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
 [exec] 
 [exec] com.lognllc.plyfe.ui.SplashActivityTest:.
 [exec] Test results for InstrumentationTestRunner=.E.
 [exec] Time: 0.019
 [exec] 
 [exec] FAILURES!!!
 [exec] Tests run: 2,  Failures: 0,  Errors: 1
 [exec] 
 [exec]
```

I can get the tests to run in Eclipse but not from ant. It's driving me up a frickin' wall, I'm hoping it's an easy fix and I'm just making some sort of n00b mistake.

Comment: Try `https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-mock/FNu7NtZh0Xk`. Upvote since Instrumentation unit test cases have a issue with getting started, not as straight forward as it sounds.